# Android - Remove file from removable SD Card using its path (Kitkat and above) issue

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sdcard, android-storage

I'm creating Android app with possibility to show images. It also allows to remove them. I have problem with dealing with removable SD Card (`KitKat` and above).

I'm prompting user to give permissions to SD Card:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), REQUEST_SD_CARD_PERMISSION);
```

Here's my code in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_SD_CARD_PERMISSION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
}
```

I have uris for images in form like this: `/storage/7255-A3FF/test/gtfht.jpeg`

When I try to delete it after calling takePersistableUriPermission(Uri, int):

```
new File("/storage/7255-A3FF/test/gtfht.jpeg").delete();
```

I get exception:

```
EACCES (Permission denied) : /storage/7255-A3FF/test/gtfht.jpeg
```

Removing files from internal storage is working fine (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is granted).

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to remove file using its path? If not how to do that?

I want to avoid situation that user should select every file using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

---

edit:

I have filesystem paths to images from

```
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
    };

    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
```

Comment: "Is it even possible to remove file using its path?" -- no. "If not how to do that?" -- stop using filesystem paths. I have no idea where you got `/storage/7255-A3FF/test/gtfht.jpeg` from. That is your problem. Persist the `Uri` to the content that you got from the Storage Access Framework (and for which you took persistable permissions). Then, you can delete the content using `DocumentFile` and the `Uri`, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited my post, take a look please.

Comment: Create the `MediaStore` `Uri` via `ContentUris`, then delete that using a `ContentResolver`, and see if it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare But when I remove file with `getContentResolver().delete("content://media/external/images/media/51950", null, null)` then file is not physically deleted from SD Card (I can see and access to it in File Manager app), it's just not visible when querying `ContentResolver`. Is it possible to remove file from SD Card?

Comment: Phooey. I thought that it would delete the underlying content along with the record. I have no good answer for you, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought so too :(